# Storing multiple values, some needing to be changed at run-time, to be referred to by a single key

Tags: c#

So my issue is I want to essentially use a dictionary, but instead of key-value pair, i want key-value-value-value pair/quad/whatever you wanna call it.  I was looking into tuple, but turns out they are immutable once set, so that's no good.  At least one of these values will be a running count, and thus changing during run-time.  Is there anything short of just making a class with multiple arrays using the index of each as the key?  Or maybe extending dictionary to have another field called "key2" or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just create your own class for the value?

```
class YourValue
{
    public int A;
    public float B;
    public string C;
}

Dicitonary<int, YourValue> yourDictionary;
```

Comment: Except I might make it a struct, if it does nothing more than store data. If you pass it around, maybe not, but in this case it should be fine.

Comment: @Magus Well that's not the only consideration, is it? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Very true, but again, this is just a type to store a couple references, much like the dictionary's own KeyValuePair.

Comment: @Rotem uh oh, does the immutable nature of the struct mean I should go with class?  I think maybe I'm a little hazy on what immutable meant.  I thought it was just implying that you can't change it during runtime.

Comment: @Timotheus: A struct isn't immutable, though your definition of immutable is correct. Collections in .Net are essentially Arrays in the IL, which means value types are often cheaper. A Dictionary is a class, but it's elements are structs, and can be changed. For a collection of stored data that will be created once, modified occasionally, and looked up often, structs aren't a bad choice at all.

Comment: @magus I know it CAN be changed, but this list on the site Rotem linked to said to avoid it unless:
"
    It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).

    It has an instance size under 16 bytes.

    It is immutable.

    It will not have to be boxed frequently."

Comment: @Timotheus They are guidelines, and Microsoft themselves break them many times in the framework (e.g. System.Drawing.Rectangle). The most important thing to consider is the reference vs. value copy semantics. Do two instances of `YourValue` with the same field values represent the exact same object?

Comment: That's less of a problem than the rest, but in the end, I've looked into it more deeply, and since Dictionary values are accessed through indexers, you won't be able to directly modify a value without replacing the whole struct, whereas a with a class you're modifying the object the dictionary references, so classes really are better in this situation.

Comment: @Magus Unless we're dealing with a very big number of short lived small objects.

Comment: @Rotem no?  At the very least they will each have a different first value (key).  What are you getting at though? Reference type -> class, value type -> struct?  Or vice versa.  Sorry, you lost me there at the end! Edit: NVM, Magus' post helped me get it.

Comment: @Timotheus: Correct! A class is a reference type and a struct is a value type. His point is that as a key, reference types can cause problems because `(new object() == new object()) == false` because each creates a new reference while `(new int() == new int()) == true` because value types *are* their values. As a value, reference types are far better. It'd be a good thing to research some time, since it can be useful.

Comment: Rotem @Magus Thanks for the help guys!  C# ninjas!